# Sending JavaScript to MongoDB for execution using the Java driver

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

I have a `.js` file on the client side that I want to send to a MongoDB instance for server-side execution.  Is this something that's possible with the Java driver?

As far as I've read, and been able to understand, `doEval()` can execute a JS stored procedure on the MongoDB server, but that's the part I am trying to avoid in this case; storing it server side.

So instead of:

```
db.doEval("myStoredFunction()")
```

I want to do something like:

```
db.doEval("function() { /* do some stuff */ }
```

Am I out of luck here or have I just not yet found the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: Your problem looks like architectural issue. You should avoid storing client side code on backend. At least use freemarker templates. Databases are for data, not for code.

Comment: Sorry @Everv0id, but you have it backwards.  I have code stored on the client side that I want to execute on the database.  Mongo supports JS functions as stored procs, but I'd rather send the JS function over in real time for execution in order to avoid managing stored procs.